# Use different JSON files as per the environment in React.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack, build, configuration

Actually, I am trying to implement the configuration file selection as per the ENV we are passing through the command line using webpack. But didn't find any solution for that. Does anyone is done this for React then please tell me how to do this?